# scrollToRowAtIndexPath in viewDidLayoutSubviews causing bug in scroll to a certain point in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    for (NSInteger i = 0 ; i < self.tableView.numberOfSections ; i ++) {
        rowCount += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }
      if (rowCount != 0 && self.firstTime==true && [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] != 0) {
self.firstTime=false;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
        
    }
```

Hello everyone. I use the above code to present to the user a specific uitableviewcell he tapped in my collection of images. When the user taps in a specific image in my collection a uitableview shows up. The user sees directly the uitableviewcell inside a uitableview he tapped in the collection of images. The problem is that when the user scrolls up or down the scrollview goes up until to the point the image is on the top of screen. The user is not able to scroll to the top of the uitableview or to the bottom.

Here is a sample video in simulator https://files.fm/f/fj96s3xrs (yes I tried it also in my iPhone and the same bug occurs)

What am i missing? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution with the help of the guys at raywenderlich so i am posting it here! The issue was that it run more than once because i didn't check correctly the firstTime variable. Also you can achieve the same functionality using less code. So use this code instead.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
 if (self.firstTime==true && [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] != 0) {
   self.firstTime=false;
           [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
           
       }
}
```

set your firstTime BOOL Variable in viewDidLoad to true.